# ControlSend, "by ahk_id" or "by ahk_parent", why such difference?

Tags: autohotkey

Please check my `ctlsend.ahk` :

```
sendi(keyspec, wintitle:="A")
{
    WinGet, winid, ID, % wintitle
    ControlSend, , % keyspec, % "ahk_id " winid
}

sendp(keyspec, wintitle:="A")
{
    ControlSend, ahk_parent, % keyspec, % wintitle
}

F1::test()
test()
{
    Sleep 1000
    sendi("{F5}{enter}")
    sendp("{F5}{enter}")
    
    sendi("F5")
    sendp("F4")
}
```

Using Autohotkey 1.1.32, Pressing <kbd>F1</kbd> on Windows 10 Notepad, I see that:

- `sendi` and `sendp` can both trigger Notepad's <kbd>F5</kbd> hotkey.
- but only `sendi` can send literal `F5` into Notepad's text area.

Why such diffrence? [ControlSend](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlSend.htm)'s doc does not seems to talk about this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After some investigation, I can finally answer my own question.

To summary:

- My `sendi()` and `sendp()` post the same window-message series to the target window.
- The difference is: `sendi()` posts to the Edit-control, and `sendp()` posts to Notepad's top-level-window.
- Edit control's window-procedure has the right code to process WM_CHAR messages, and renders those accompanied characters on its client-area.
- Notepad top-level-window's window-procedure does NOT have code to process WM_CHAR messages, and WM_CHAR messages destined to it are merely discarded. This is the reason why `sendp("F5")` has no effect.

Then why a WM_KEYDOWN message with `vkcode==VK_F5` takes the same effect for `sendi` and `sendp`? The reasons is Notepad's message-loop calls WinAPI [TranslateAccelerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-translateacceleratora). The `VK_F5` is defined as an Accelerator-key that would internally trigger [Insert Date/Time] WM_COMMAND action. Since `VK_F5` is an Accelerator-key, it now does not matter a WM_KEYDOWN message with `vkcode==VK_F5` is posted to Edit-control or top-level-window. That is the rule of using Accelerator-key.

I got the above conclusion with the help of a very useful program named SpyEx, https://www.the-sz.com/products/spyex/ .

[image: SpyEx - start spying window message of Notepad]

[image: Effective table]

[image: Spying sendi() generated messages]

[image: Spying sendp() generated messages]

In order to get screenshots above, I need to call `sendi` and `sendp` separately, so the updated `sendip.ahk`:

```
global g_wintitle := "Untitled - Notepad"

sendi(keyspec, wintitle:="A")
{
    WinGet, winid, ID, % wintitle
    ControlSend, , % keyspec, % "ahk_id " winid
}

sendp(keyspec, wintitle:="A")
{
    ControlSend, ahk_parent, % keyspec, % wintitle
}

F1::do_sendi() ; Press F1 anywhere to sendi-to Notepad Edit-control
do_sendi()
{
    Sleep 100
    sendi("{F5}{enter}", g_wintitle)
    sendi("F5", g_wintitle)
}

F2::do_sendp() ; Press F2 anywhere to sendp-to Notepad top-level-window
do_sendp()
{
    Sleep 100
    sendp("{F5}{enter}", g_wintitle)
    sendp("F4", g_wintitle)
}
```